# In Game Dev Tycoon, How do I exit the garage

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

I have made some successful games and now I have a
lot of money, but when I was given the option to progress I accidently clicked no. I was just wondering how do I progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, the game will ask you again in the future if you want to move from your garage.